# RxJava Observable on error fetch items from database but still pass error through

Tags: kotlin, observable, rx-java, rx-java2

In my application I am getching data from api and if there is an error while doing that I would like to get data from database but also show error message on the screen.
So how I thought about doing this is use something like `onErrorResumeNext`. I can get data from database using this but the problem is that `onError` is not called then and I can't show error message to user. So my code is:

```
override fun getData(): Observable<List<MyData>> {
    return getDataFromApi().onErrorResumeNext(getDataFromDatabase())
}
```

How can I somehow fetch database on error and simultaneously know that error message needs to be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the way you model the domain to something like the following:

```
sealed class Result {
    class Simple(data: List<MyData>) : Result()

    class HasError(data: List<MyData>, throwable: Throwable) : Result()
}
```

Then you can do:

```
fun getResult(): Observable<Result> {
    return getDataFromApi().map<Result> { Result.Simple(it) }
        .onErrorResumeNext { throwable ->
            getDataFromDatabase().map { myDataList ->
                Result.HasError(
                    myDataList,
                    throwable
                )
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: When I am trying to map database result to Result.HasError inside onErrorResumeNext then I am getting Expected types mismatch, required ObservableSource found Observable

Comment: @matip what version of RxJava is this? The `onErrorResumeNext` signature should be the following `public final Observable<T> onErrorResumeNext(@NonNull Function<? super Throwable, ? extends ObservableSource<? extends T>> fallbackSupplier)`